# Best way to show accepted item that applies to multiple inputs?

Tags: interaction-design, tables, modal-windows, cta

I wanted to get insights on the best way to show an accepted item.Suppose we have list of offers and one offer that applies to multiple lines ( mobile numbers) i.e XXX-XXX-XXX1, XXX-XXX-XXX2, XXX-XXX-XXX3 etc. as shown in the below image :

**Variation 1: On click on Accept cta, the row expands and shows the lines which can be accepted.** [Prototype link](https://www.figma.com/proto/mE7K2n0BzjqTETwJs919Gb/UX?type=design&node-id=201-2&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%3A1&starting-point-node-id=201%3A2&show-proto-sidebar=1)

[image]

[image]

**Variation 2 : On click on Accept cta, a modal popup appears with all the lines listed vertically and can be scrollable :** [Prototype link](https://www.figma.com/proto/mE7K2n0BzjqTETwJs919Gb/UX?type=design&node-id=201-929&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%3A1&starting-point-node-id=201%3A929&show-proto-sidebar=1)

[image]

[image]

I wanted to know if which is better out of these two and if there are better ways to show the information. Thanks in advance